# Web API is it necessary to have ViewModels layer classes?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel, dto

When I use Web (MVC), I always to create a separate classes layer. These classes often the same as DTO classes, but with attributes like `[Display(Name = "Street")]` and validation. But for web api Display attributes are not necessary, validation can be used by FluentValidation. Should Api controller returns ViewModels classes or DTO classes will be fine too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer, as always is .... it depends.

If your API is serving multiple clients , apps etc, then returning DTOs is a better options.

ViewModels are specific to the MVC client and should already be prepared for display, meaning the data should already be formatted in a specific way, some fields maybe combined, they should satisfy whatever requirements the display pages have. They are called ViewNodels for a reason. The point is that they are rarely exactly the same as the data the API returns, which should be a bit more generic and follow a certain pattern to make sense to its users.

If your ViewModels are exactly the same and you only have one client then it's up to you if you want to create a set of duplicated classed just to avoid having the attributes.

Mapping from DTO to ViewModel and viceversa is not exactly complicated, but the process does introduce one more complication, one more layer.

Don't forget one thing though. API DTOs are supposed to return the data they have on any entity regardless of the requirements of any UI. Requirements can change anyway, new fields added or discarded. You're more than likely to leave the API alone when that happens and simply change your ViewModels.

Your ViewModels are specific to a UI page and should contain only the data required by that page. This means that you can end up with multiple ViewModels for the same data, it's just that the display requirements are different for each.

My vote goes towards keeping the ViewModels and DTOs separate, even if, at this point in time they are exactly the same. Thins always change and this is one of those things you can actually be ready for.

Comment: so, you propose to always have VM for MVC, and use DTO for API?

Comment: exactly, it introduces a separation layer and it allows you to add multiple clients all being served with DTOs

Comment: but API is a client layer too :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on application's architecture how we want to return response. In this case yes we can return DTO classes but i think that would not be the good approach because we should create a separate Resource classes that will map with DTO and then return. Just see the below example:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerResource
{
    [JsonObject]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonObject]
    public string Department { get; set; }

}
```

Suppose we have CustomerDTO class and we want to return response in the following json format

```
 {
"name":"Abc xyz",
"department":"Testing"
}
```

So in this case we should we have separate class that will return as a response to the end user as i created CustomerResource. In this scenario we will create a mapper that will map DTO with resource object.
And also with this implementation we can test resources independently

Comment: seems to me, returned Dto will have the same JSON format (not depending on `[JsonObject]` attribute). Of course, when returned model is different that DTO model it would be better to create view model, but when it's the same... Any reasons to create viewModel? `[JsonObject]` attribute is a reason, but no sense in this attribute in our case...

Comment: Actually i have given answer based on my current application, we have a product payment gateway where we provide REST APIs to our merchants and we are using the micro services architecture so we have created a common resources(i.e ViewModels) which is shared by multiple micro services(to implement the DRY principle)  and yes you are right there is no use of [JsonObject] in your case.

Comment: so what do you gain by having these Resource classes? also when you say you test resources independently, what do you mean? The resource is a simple class with no functionality so what exactly are you testing?